# Using prefixes for private properties while returning whole object without them

Tags: typescript

I've got an object dashboard instantiated with a Dashboard class:

```
export class Dashboard {
  private _id: string;
  private _name: string;
  private _dashboardComponents: DashboardComponent[];

  constructor() {
    this._id = someGenerator();
    this._name = 'some name';
    this._dashboardComponents = [];
  }

  get id(): string {
    return this._id;
  }

  get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
  }

  ...
}
```

Due to the usage of typescript's getters and setters I was forced to prefix my private properties with an underscore. Now I would like to push my data to the server, but once I send the whole object, all of its properties are with an underscore. What is the best way to get rid of them while using an instance of such class.

Comment: Why are you using getters/setters in the first place? They don't do anything in your 
code.

Comment: They encapsulate my properties. You cannot define id from anywhere else in the code.

Comment: If you want to protect your `id` from changing, you could use `Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {value: myID, writable: false})`. Or you could also `Object.freeze` your object

Comment: Or set a property to `readonly`. My implementation is correct with a documentation of typescript and I was just curious whether there is a solution for my use case.

Comment: `readonly` is a typescript concept and it does not protect a property from changing. It doesn't even compile to JS. I've given you 3 solutions already BTW.

Comment: Just like typescript interfaces, but we still use them to make our development easier. Thank you for your help, but I expected there is some feature I've overlooked that would keep my model as it is right now.

Comment: If you want only type-assistance during development, and you don't care about runtime behavior, then using `readonly` is enough and getters/setters are redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether this is the best way or not I'll leave to you to decide. I did think about using the replacer function within `JSON.stringify` to achieve it, but I think it is probably more readable to...

## Copy to Plain Object

You can copy into an object like this:

```
class Dashboard {
    private _id: string = 'id';
    private _name: string = 'name';
    private _dashboardComponents: any[] = ['a', 'b'];

    get id(): string {
        return this._id;
    }

    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(value: string) {
        this._name = value;
    }

    toContract() {
        const result = {};
        for (let key in this) {
            result[key.replace('_', '')] = this[key];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
const db = new Dashboard();

// {"_id":"id","_name":"name","_dashboardComponents":["a","b"]}
console.log(JSON.stringify(db));

//{"id":"id","name":"name","dashboardComponents":["a","b"]}
console.log(JSON.stringify(db.toContract()));
```

You could perform more dratic transformations - and even make it work on hierarchical objects.

## Delagate to a Plain Object

You could delegate to a plain object instead:

```
class DashboardContract {
    id: string = 'id';
    name: string = 'name';
    dashboardComponents: any[] = ['a', 'b'];
}

class Dashboard {
    private _contract = new DashboardContract();

    get contract(): DashboardContract {
        return this._contract;
    }

    get id(): string {
        return this._contract.id;
    }

    get name(): string {
        return this._contract.name;
    }

    set name(value: string) {
        this._contract.name = value;
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(new Dashboard().contract));
```

## Convolute the TypeScript Side

You could keep the serializable names clean, and come up with a way to name things on the TypeScript side of the fence:

```
class Dashboard {
    private id: string = 'id';
    private name: string = 'name';
    private dashboardComponents: any[] = ['a', 'b'];

    get identity(): string {
        return this.id;
    }

    get dashboardName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }

    set dashboardName(value: string) {
        this.name = value;
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(new Dashboard()));
```

Comment: It is the idea I had, but I believe it will cost us much work with nested properties in the long run and probable changes in the models.

Comment: You could make it work recursively, and move it to a class where it could be shared. Or keep the keys that will be serialized correctly named. Or delegate from a wrapper to a clean object?

Comment: Do you believe it is worth a hassle or is better to change the structure of my class?

Comment: @KamilZaharan - I've added a couple of other options. I thought you could choose which works best based on the extent of this in your program.

Comment: @KamilZaharan Sorry if I've hurt your feelings, but you had hurt my feelings as well by not being able to clearly explain what you really want, making me feel like I waste my time. Also, thanks for upvoting, I for some reason thought the upvote wasn't from you. This actually changes everything.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to execute some logic when a value is being set/get, then
I'd suggest you to use Proxies, instead of getters/setters.

```
class Dashboard {
  private id: string;
  private name: string;
  private dashboardComponents: DashboardComponent[];

  constructor() {
    this.id = someGenerator();
    this.name = 'some name';
    this.dashboardComponents = [];
  }
}

const instance = new Dashboard()
const proxy = new Proxy(instance, {
   get() { /*...*/},
   set() { /*...*/}
})

JSON.stringify(proxy) // no underscores
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy